# Como somar um ano específico com o ano atual em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Quero criar uma função em javascript que some o ano 1993 + ano_atual e que insira o resultado dentro do meu `<span class="title_25anos" id="calculo_ano"></span></h1>`

E este é o meu código.

```
<script>

    var ano_inicio = 1993;
    var ano_atual = getFullYear();

    var soma_ano = ano_inicio + ano_atual;

    document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " . soma_ano . "anos com você";

</script>
```

Comment: Qual valor vc espera retorna?

Comment: 2019 - 1993 = 26 Porém esse valor precisa ser automático.

Comment: Existe outro problema `22/05/1993` `11/02/2019` retornar 26,sendo diferença de 25

Comment: Valor da diferença de ano vai ser exato ou aproximado?

Comment: Será aproximado

Comment: `document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " . soma_ano . "anos com você";` Porque tem esses pontos? Isso não é php,mas sim javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá.

Para acha diferença de segundos,anos,e qualquer coisa.

Você calcular vF - vI.

vF = Valor final.

vI = Valor inicial.

Solução:

```html
<script>

    var ano_inicio = 1993;
    var data = new Date();
    var ano_atual = +data.getFullYear();

    var soma_ano = Math.abs(ano_atual - ano_inicio);
// return 26

    document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " + soma_ano + "anos com você";

</script>
```

Eu espero ter ajudado. Boa tarde!

Comment: Mas porque o resultado aparece assim "HÁ -26 ANOS COM VOCÊ"

Comment: E agora? Funcionou?

Comment: Show!!! Muito obrigado!